# jQuery add class to href if link contains specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, href

I have some dynamically populated links in a list on my site that link to files. Is it possible to use jQuery to see if the name of the file ends with .pdf and add a class to the href or similar if the link text ends with .mp3?

For example I have the following links in my list:

- Document1.pdf
- Song1.mp3
- Song2.m4a
- Document2.doc

I would like to detect the end letters and add different classes to the links, so to the link which has the text Document1.pdf I'd add the class `pdf` to the anchor element, and the link with the text Song1.mp3 I'd add the class `mp3` to the anchor element.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use the attribute selector:

```
$('a[href$=".mp3"]')...
```

Options:

```
    Attribute Contains Prefix Selector [name|="value"]
    Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value 
    either equal to a given string or starting with that string followed 
    by a hyphen (-).

    Attribute Contains Selector [name*="value"]
    Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a 
    value containing the a given substring.

    Attribute Contains Word Selector [name~="value"]
    Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value
    containing a given word, delimited by spaces.

    Attribute Ends With Selector [name$="value"]
    Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a 
    value ending exactly with a given string. The comparison is case sensitive.

    Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]
    Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a 
    value exactly equal to a certain value.

    Attribute Not Equal Selector [name!="value"]
    Select elements that either don’t have the specified attribute, 
    or do have the specified attribute but not with a certain value.

    Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"]
    Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a 
    value beginning exactly with a given string.

    Has Attribute Selector [name]
    Selects elements that have the specified attribute, with any value.

    Multiple Attribute Selector [name="value"][name2="value2"]
    Matches elements that match all of the specified attribute filters.
```

[Check out the API](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) for additional information.

Answer (score 1):

given your all such links have class `.file`

```
var exts = ['pdf','xls'];
$('a.file').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('href').match(new RegExp('('+exts.join('|')+')'), 'gi'))
        $(this).addClass($(this).attr('href').match(/\w{3}$/gi)[0]);
})
```

This code will add the *extension* class to all such links that have file extension in `exts` array.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than hard coding all the types, you can also make a solution that will automatically do this for all your links:

```
var regex = "/\..{3,4}$/";
$('a').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass(regex.match($(this).attr("href"))[0]
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('a[href$=".mp3"]').addClass("mp3");
$('a[href$=".pdf"]').addClass("pdf");
```

Comment: Erm, perhaps the second one should say

Comment: `$('a[href$=".pdf"]').addClass("pdf");`