# How to find hidden links?

Tags: javascript, php, html, python-3.x, web-scraping

Is there anyway to find hidden links through either javascript or python scripts?

For example:

```
http://www.barneys.com/product/adidas-originals-by-kanye-west-yeezy-boost-350-v2-sneakers-504886623.html?
```

This link is still live but when I search for yeezy or any of keywords from above link, It wouldn't come up. How come it still exists?

Comment: hidden how now?

Comment: Well like I mentioned, if I go to http://www.barneys.com/search and search for yeezy, the product doesn't show up. If I go here, http://www.barneys.com/designer/adidas-originals-by-kanye-west/men/shoes/sneakers/N-kwqlktZj68mm4, it is not showing up. There is no way to search for this product unless I know that actual link

Comment: i dont see how you consider that "hidden" it is simply not indexed by a particular search engine

Comment: Well how would I grab a link that is not indexed? Or is it impossible

Comment: Well you obviously found it. So i don't understand  what you want.

Comment: I would like to know if possible to find links that are not indexded? Says there is product releasing this weekend. I would like to find that link day before it releases. And just generally curious on how to find the link when it not indexed yet. I found the link on pastebin.

Answer (score -1):

What is the code you used that failed?
If you need a specific selector to fetch an anchor tag containing a certain word, you can search for it using this syntax:

```
 $('a[href*="SomeWordIntTheHref"]')
```

...from this page:

[jQuery add class to href if link contains specific text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879130/jquery-add-class-to-href-if-link-contains-specific-text)

Comment: I haven't even written a code yet because I don't know how to start it. I still can't make sense why the link i provide still works but I can't search for it on the website at all.

Comment: this a comment not an answer